# GUnicorn not showing up locally, not using any ports (Django)

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

I am trying to run a Docker container via the command:

`docker run --rm -d  projectname:latest`

The gunicorn command which is executing is:

`gunicorn projectname.wsgi 0.0.0.0:$PORT`

And I get the following gunicorn lines:

```
[2020-07-28 11:56:50 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (10)
[2020-07-28 11:56:50 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-07-28 11:56:50 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
```

From this I thought it was working fine. However, nothing is showing up in 127.0.0.1:8000. After using Network Utility's port scanner, no ports above or including 8000 are being used.

When I right click on the container in Visual Studio Code (with Docker extension installed) and click 'Open in Browser' it states "No valid ports are available. Source: Docker (Extension)".

How can I see the app running locally? What could the issue possibly be?

Comment: "if it's only listening on `127.0.0.1:8000` then it's not binding to all interfaces, and won't get requests from outside. `0.0.0.0:8000`", it should listen on `0.0.0.0:8000`.

Comment: @Adiii so what should I change? My binding options? It is currently gunicorn projectname.wsgi 0.0.0.0:$PORT so what should I change it to?

Comment: Please look into your code , it should not display `Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (10 )` if it listening on all interfaces.

Comment: change command to `gunicorn projectname.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`